# whats wrong with my SQL command

Tags: server, mysql

first of all I am following this [tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-administration.htm).

as they mentioned I am writing my query as:

```
mysql> grant select
    -> on play.*
    -> to 'guest' @ 'localhost'
    -> IDENTIFIED BY '459459';
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''localhost'
IDENTIFIED BY '459459'' at line 3
mysql>
```

but I am still getting an error. What is it that I am doing wrong?

Comment: The only thing I can see is the spacing `-> to 'guest' @ 'localhost'` should be `-> TO 'guest'@'localhost'`, but I'm not sure if it really matters about the spacing or not. **The main error is that there should be a capital TO & ON PLAY**

Comment: @SimplySimon as I know the capital words or small words doesnt make difference.

Comment: Can you post the first three lines of your file in your question. If these are the first three lines then the error is on the third line. Therefore I suggest `-> TO 'guest'@'localhost'`

Comment: @SimplySimon oh my god you are amazing .... that worked. I have removed the space. please make it as answer. I will accept that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer, looking at the link you gave appears to be either the capitalisation of the key words, TO or the fact that you have placed a space either side of the `@` in line 3.

Present:

```
-> to 'guest' @ 'localhost'
```

Correct syntax

```
-> TO 'guest'@'localhost'
```